# Using c# code in powershell scripts

Tags: c#, powershell

I've been trying to convert my C# code into PowerShell, but I'm not successful. I tried to research documents about PowerShell and try each one of them, unfortunately, nothing work for me. My C# code is working in Visual Studio 2015, but I was not able to embed and work it in PowerShell.

My C# code is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NLog;
using Nop.Core.Domain;
namespace Tasks
{

    public class ReleaseExpiredHoldsJob : ScheduledJob
    {
        private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private readonly IRepository<Shelf> _shelfRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<ProductVariant> _productVariantRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<OrderProductVariant> _orderProductVariantRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<OrderTaskProductVariant> _orderTaskProductVariantRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<OrderTask> _orderTaskRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Order> _orderRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<StockWarning> _stockWarningRepository;

        public ReleaseExpiredHoldsJob(IRepository<Shelf> shelfRepository, IRepository<ProductVariant> productVariantRepository, IRepository<OrderProductVariant> orderProductVariantRepository, IRepository<OrderTaskProductVariant> orderTaskProductVariantRepository, IRepository<OrderTask> orderTaskRepository, IRepository<Order> orderRepository, IRepository<StockWarning> stockWarningRepository)
        {
            _shelfRepository = shelfRepository;
            _productVariantRepository = productVariantRepository;
            _orderProductVariantRepository = orderProductVariantRepository;
            _orderTaskProductVariantRepository = orderTaskProductVariantRepository;
            _orderTaskRepository = orderTaskRepository;
            _orderRepository = orderRepository;
            _stockWarningRepository = stockWarningRepository;
        }

        protected override Task Run()
        {
            using (var scope = TransactionScopeExtensions.AsyncScope())
            {
                var irregularHolds = (
                    from s in _shelfRepository.Table
                    group s by s.ProductVariantId
                    into sg
                    let currentHold = sg.Sum(s => s.QuantityOnHold)
                    join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on sg.Key equals pv.Id
                    join opv in _orderProductVariantRepository.Table on pv.Id equals opv.ProductVariantId
                    join otpv in _orderTaskProductVariantRepository.Table on opv.Id equals otpv.OrderProductVariantId
                    join ot in _orderTaskRepository.Table on otpv.OrderTaskId equals ot.Id
                    join o in _orderRepository.Table on ot.OrderId equals o.Id
                    where
                        ot.OrderTaskStatusId == (byte) OrderTaskStatus.Processing &&
                        !otpv.Completed && (ot.OrderTaskTypeId == (byte) OrderTaskType.WarehousePick ||
                                            ot.OrderTaskTypeId == (byte) OrderTaskType.WarehouseExport) &&
                        o.DeliveryWindowEnd > DateTimeOffset.Now &&
                        (o.OrderStatusId == (int) OrderStatus.Pending || o.OrderStatusId == (int) OrderStatus.Processing)
                    group new {currentHold, pv, otpv} by pv.Id
                    into g
                    let expectedHold = g.Sum(t => t.otpv.Quantity - t.otpv.Fulfilled - t.otpv.Failed)
                    let currentHold = g.Min(t => t.currentHold)
                    where expectedHold != currentHold
                    select
                        new
                        {
                            ProductVariantId = g.Key,
                            ExpectedHold = expectedHold,
                            CurrentHold = currentHold
                        }).ToList();

                Logger.Info("Processing {0} irregular holds", irregularHolds.Count);

                foreach (var hold in irregularHolds)
                {
                    Logger.Info("Processing irregular holds for product variant id {0}", hold.ProductVariantId);

                    var shelves =
                        _shelfRepository.Table.Where(

                            s => s.QuantityOnHold > 0 && s.ProductVariantId == hold.ProductVariantId)
                            .Include(s => s.ProductVariant)
                            .Include(s => s.ProductVariant.Product)
                            .ToList();

                    if (hold.CurrentHold > hold.ExpectedHold)
                    {
                        var excessHold = hold.CurrentHold - hold.ExpectedHold;
                        foreach (var shelf in shelves)
                        {
                            var toDeduct = Math.Min(excessHold, shelf.QuantityOnHold);
                            shelf.QuantityOnHold -= toDeduct;
                            _shelfRepository.Update(shelf, false);

                            excessHold -= toDeduct;

                            _stockWarningRepository.Insert(new StockWarning
                            {
                                StockWarningType = StockWarningType.ExcessHold,
                                ExpectedQuantity = hold.ExpectedHold,
                                WasQuantity = hold.CurrentHold,
                                AdjustedQuantity = shelf.QuantityOnHold,
                                ShelfName = shelf.Name,
                                ProductVariantId = hold.ProductVariantId
                            }, false);

                            Logger.Warn("Hold Quantity reduced from {0} to {1} on shelf {2} for product variant {3}",
                                hold.CurrentHold, shelf.QuantityOnHold, shelf.Name, shelf.ProductVariant.Product.Name);
                        }

                        if (excessHold > 0)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("excessHold is greater than 0");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (hold.CurrentHold < hold.ExpectedHold)
                    {

                        _stockWarningRepository.Insert(new StockWarning
                        {
                            StockWarningType = StockWarningType.NotEnoughHold,
                            ExpectedQuantity = hold.ExpectedHold,
                            WasQuantity = hold.CurrentHold,
                            ShelfName = string.Join(", ", shelves),
                            ProductVariantId = hold.ProductVariantId
                        }, false);

                        Logger.Warn("Not enough hold warning for required {0}, has {1} for product variant Id {2}",
                                hold.CurrentHold, hold.ProductVariantId);
                    }
                }

                _shelfRepository.SaveChanges();
                _stockWarningRepository.SaveChanges();

                scope.Complete();
            }

            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
}
```

In my PowerShell code, I just put

```psh
$source = @"
```

at the begging of this code and

```psh
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source
[Tasks.ReleaseExpiredHoldsJob]::Run()
```

at the end of the code, but it don't work.

When I execute I always get the following error:

```
Add-Type : c:\Users\Team\AppData\Local\Temp\f1ng1wni.0.cs(1) : A
namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\Users\Team\AppData\Local\Temp\f1ng1wni.0.cs(1) : >>> ddd
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users\Tea...elds or methods:CompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

I have got this error for every line of the code.

Comment: Are you trying to convert `C#` code to `Powershell` code or to run `C#` code in `Powershell`?

Comment: Initial Plan is to convert c# code to Powershell, but I am totally new to this so thought to give a try by making c# code to run in Powershell, hints on both will be appreciated

Comment: I would suggest you to look at `PSCmdlet` let your class extend from `PSCmdlet` and call your method in `Cmdlet.ProcessRecord()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscmdlet%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Doesn't work how? What error message(s)?

Comment: @Sybren Thanks for your suggestion, can you post a snippet of it, It will surely help me to understand it better

Comment: @briantist: I get the following error

Add-Type : c:\Users\team\AppData\Local\Temp\f1ng1wni.0.cs(1) : A namespace cannot directly contain members such as 
fields or methods
c:\Users\Deepak Ravisankar\AppData\Local\Temp\f1ng1wni.0.cs(1) : >>> ddd
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users\Deepak...elds or methods:CompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Comment: @ravi I think this tutorial will put you in the right direction http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/18/writing-a-powershell-module-in-c-part-1-the-basics/

Comment: You can always just compile this code to a dll and use add-type (or reflection) to load it. Getting this code to work in PS is tricky since you also need to reference most of the stuff in the using statements. Also about the current code : i noticed that using the full classname and namespace (so for instance system.bla.classname instead of classname) can also precent a lot of errors like these when embedding c# source in PS

Comment: There is no `ddd` in the code you posted. Please show your actual code and error message, not something you fabricated or typed from memory.

Comment: MSDN is all you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602028.ASPX
I would go with a C# commandlet option. What you are trying to do is overkill for ad hoc C# in PowerShell. Loading all assemblies that are explicitly or implicitly used is very difficult and hardly justifiable in this case. Also, there is no out of the box replacement for Linq in PS.